# using tshark with timestamp and flags

Tags: packet-capture, tshark

I am trying to use tshark with a few flags and also get timestamp for each filtered trace. I am using this to filter all the DNS queries in my system. 
I am not able to get the time stamps along with the filters working. For instance if i try something like

```
tshark -t ad -n -T fields -e ip.src -e dns.qry.name -f 'dst port 53' -Y "dns.flags.response eq 0"
```

I get the output as I want

```
192.168.1.3 clientservices.googleapis.com
192.168.1.3 play.google.com
192.168.1.3 play.google.com
```

I get the timestamp with

```
 tshark -t ad 
    1 2018-09-02 21:12:20.536204429 61.223.125.209 → 192.168.1.3  UDP 174 12929 → 51465 Len=132
    2 2018-09-02 21:12:20.536355008  192.168.1.3 → 61.223.125.209 UDP 126 51465 → 12929 Len=84
    3 2018-09-02 21:12:20.599264715  192.168.1.3 → 176.31.225.118 TCP 54 45942 → 80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=30016 Len=0
```

However I am not able to get both working together. Though the command runs it just outputs without the timestamp.

```
tshark -t ad -T fields -e ip.src -e dns.qry.name -Y "dns.flags.response eq 0"
  192.168.1.3 captive.apple.com
  192.168.1.3 myip.opendns.com
  192.168.1.3 ipv4.icanhazip.com
  192.168.1.3 slack.com
```

Any pointers that can help in this regard. I am using tshark version 2.2.6 on Debian 9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your command, `-t ad` has no effect because `-T fields` overrides the output format. You'll need to display the timestamp as a new field in your `fields` format, using `-e frame.time`:

```
$ tshark -n -T fields -e frame.time -e ip.src -e dns.qry.name -f 'dst port 53' -Y "dns.flags.response eq 0"
Capturing on 'eno1'
Sep  3, 2018 15:49:46.354055274 CEST    10.0.0.1    google.co.uk
Sep  3, 2018 15:49:52.034315960 CEST    10.0.0.1    google.jp
Sep  3, 2018 15:49:54.561493702 CEST    10.0.0.1    google.cn
```